# Use MAME debugger for Amiga software

Tags: amiga, debugging, mame

I have used the MAME debugger a lot with arcade machine emus.

Now I would like to use it to help debug a game I build for Amiga. Having set up A500 emulation in MAME by adding the roms, I can start it, but I cannot enter the debugger.

Using '-debug' option does not work. There is also no config-menu on 'TAB'. I cannot find it on the mame documentation. It seems quite sparse on home-computers.

Is there a way to use the debugger here?

I using MAME 0.226 with this commandline:

```
mame64.exe a2000n -debug -flop C:\AMIGA\g.adf
```

MAME is build from source, so if the solution requires changing some compiler options or such, this is no issue.

Comment: I would believe that asking on a [Mame](https://www.mamedev.org/) related forum might be a far better way to get on the spot information, wouldn't it? Especially if you're looking for source level hints. Also, this question is about the emulator, not the emulated machine, so clearly off topic for RC.SE.

Comment: I'd suggest that you learn how to use the WinUAE built-in debugger. It has a lot of amiga only features.

Comment: Now someone closed the question without noting who it was, and no note on where it would be less "off topic". So I cannot even ask him.

Comment: Ok I can use the WinUAE debugger. It is pretty crude and by far not as comfortable as the one in MAME, so the question remains.

Comment: I'm going to vote to reopen this. It's exactly as much on topic as, say, CC65, or many kinds of assembly language.